# Spring MVC parse POST cross domain request missed parameters in IE browser

Tags: spring-mvc, cors

I have two applications on different domains: *foo.bar.com* and *bar.com*
And I try to send request from first domain to second. For this, I've added a filter to the *second* domain to web.xml:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

And for all browsers it works, except IE browser.
For IE I've added special condition for the firt server ob JS:

```
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
            var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
            xdr.open("POST", "http://bar.com/user/login");
            var loginParam = get param here;
            var passParam = get param here;
            xdr.send("login=" + loginParam + "&password=" + passParam);
            xdr.onerror = function () {
                alert('in error');
            };
            xdr.onload = function () {
                alert(xdr.responseText);
            }
        } else {
            //Simple AJAX request
        }
    });
```

After this, I've got the request on my server filter! *But* I don't have parameters: *login* and *password* they are missed. 
What should I do in the situation? How can I execute Cross domain POST request in IE?

Comment: How are you verifying that the login/password is not reaching the server? Can you do a network trace to see if the body is included in the actual HTTP request? Also read the following post to learn about the limitations of IE's XDomainRequest: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

Comment: I have debugged in IE console, the two params were sent to server normaly. Than, started my debug in Java application, and no params in the request

Comment: Can you include a snapshot of what the request looks like in IE? Also, where are you starting your Java debugging from? Is it before, during, or after the CORS filter? Are there any filters or code that run before your Java snapshot?

Comment: There is a screen of parameters, which send IE to the server (the same for other browsers), but after IE call, Spring MVC controller doesn't get such params. http://screencast.com/t/Fcb1rZexgl7

Comment: Did you figure out an answer to this @Andrew? I am seeing similar behavior in ASP .NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. It turns out that for IE8/IE9, [XDocumentRequest does not set the Content-Type header](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) on the request. It defaults to `text/plain`.

Server frameworks such as Spring MVC will not bind form parameters unless the Content-Type is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So you'll need to do something custom on the server to bind the form parameters.